# Django error message displayed for unique fields

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to change the default error message when duplicate entries try to save when they should be unique i.e. `unique=True`. Much like this:

```
email = models.EmailField(unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"This email has already been registered."})
```

But, `unique` in the above case was a guess, and doesn't work. Neither can I find out what the name of the error actually is. Does anyone know the correct name?

Note, this validation is model level, not form validation.

EDIT:
A bit more info, at the moment the current error message is displayed by `form.errors`:

```
[model_name] with this [field_label] already exists
```

Which isn't very user friendly, so I wanted to override it...

Comment: `unique` is a field option: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#unique

Comment: In your title you're talking about an IntegrityError, which is raised when trying to save a instance which has a value that isn't unique, see: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique

Comment: @Bjorn, maybe my title is a bit confusing. I've amended it. I want to override the standard error message, but I don't know the name of the error message. I assumed it was called `unique` but maybe not. Maybe I can't override it this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error message is apparently hard-coded in the `django/db/models/base.py` file.

```
def unique_error_message(self, model_class, unique_check):
    opts = model_class._meta
    model_name = capfirst(opts.verbose_name)

    # A unique field
    if len(unique_check) == 1:
        field_name = unique_check[0]
        field_label = capfirst(opts.get_field(field_name).verbose_name)
        # Insert the error into the error dict, very sneaky
        return _(u"%(model_name)s with this %(field_label)s already exists.") %  {
            'model_name': unicode(model_name),
            'field_label': unicode(field_label)
        }
    # unique_together
    else:
        field_labels = map(lambda f: capfirst(opts.get_field(f).verbose_name), unique_check)
        field_labels = get_text_list(field_labels, _('and'))
        return _(u"%(model_name)s with this %(field_label)s already exists.") %  {
            'model_name': unicode(model_name),
            'field_label': unicode(field_labels)
        }
```

One way to solve this is to create your custom model derived from `EmailField` and override the `unique_error_message` method. But beware that it might break things when you upgrade to newer versions of Django.

Comment: Right. Thank you. I have also found this ticket http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8913 Hopefully that will be implemented one day...

Answer (score 54):

Thank you very much.

```
email = models.EmailField(unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"This email has already been registered."})
```

this worked very well now.

If you want to customise error_messages like `invalided`, do it in `forms.ModelForm`

```
email = forms.EmailField(error_messages={'invalid': 'Your email address is incorrect'})
```

But `unique` message should be customised in `model` field, as ben mentioned

```
email = models.EmailField(unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"This email has already been registered."})
```

Comment: Upvoted. The first one worked in my case

Answer (score 4):

Since Django 1.4 the exact example you supply actually works. Maybe they found your error report and just fixed it?

https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.20/django/db/models/base.py#L780

Answer (score 0):

The unique error message is constructed by `django.db.models.base.unique_error_message` (at least on Django 1.3).