# How to change the default error message of username in Django

Tags: python, django

I wanna change the default error message of `username` of `User` in `models.py`.

My simple custom user model is like this.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  nickname = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, null=True)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/', null=True)
```

I did put the below code in `models.py`, but it seems it doesn't work. Why is this wrong?

```
User._meta.get_field('username').error_messsages = {
            'unique': _('New message'),
        }
```

Comment: Hey @Gianna. You might find solution for your problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514621/django-error-message-displayed-for-unique-fields

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    nickname = models.CharField(unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"This is error message for unique parameter."})
```

)

You can read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#error-messages